# .htaccess remove public folder and index.php in subdirectory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building an API which is devided in subfolders. Version one of this api is located in api.com/v1 and the next version is version four, which is located in /v4.

Version one wasn't using any framework and was just straight PHP. Version 4 of the api is using Laravel as its base. Thus resulting in a public folder. I don't want the API urls to be like 'api.com/v4/public/entry'.

Filtering the index.php out of the URL's worked just fine with the provided .htaccess, but i didn't get it to filter out the public folder and the index.php file, while keeping the v4 subdirectory in the URL.

I'm not sure if this is even possible at all.

So `api.com/v4/img/banner.png` should link to `api.com/v4/public/img/banner.png`.
And `api.com/v4/gis/layer1.xml` should link to `api.com/v4/public/index.php/gis/layer1.xml`

here goes my .htaccess file so far, which is located in the v4 folder. (modified version of the .htaccess file located in the public folder used to filter out 'index.php' from the URL.)

```
RewriteEngine On

# add basic auth support
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: A rewrite including `/gis/` should include `index.php/gis` in the rewrite? Sure?

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working for you? Also show `/v4/public/.htaccess`, if that exists.

Comment: I removed the .htaccess file from the public folder, and used this one in the v4 folder instead. Right now the URI comming trough in the controller is incorrect (eg : v4/gis/layer1 instead of gis/layer1). Also css files are not loaded correctly.